# bootstrap mutliple level expand collapse with jquery ajax data response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I need this below using JSON data response, Please help me... appreciated in advance

Actually i need the multi level expand collapse with JSON data response using jquery ajax...

I'm new in the ajax so please help in the json data with expnad collapse plugin..

All level data should be fetched from json file like below,

```
$.ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "viz/getcachedata",
                        contentType : "application/json",
                        dataType : "json",
                        async : false,
                        success : function(data) {
                            $('#menulistitem1').append(data);
                        }

                        });
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        .menu .accordion-heading {  position: relative; }
    .menu .accordion-heading .edit {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 30px; 
    }
    .menu .area { border-left: 4px solid #f38787; }
    .menu .equipamento { border-left: 4px solid #65c465; }
    .menu .ponto { border-left: 4px solid #98b3fa; }
    .menu .collapse.in { overflow: visible; }
        </style>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="menu">
                    <div class="accordion">
                        <!-- Áreas -->
                        <div class="accordion-group">
                            <!-- Área -->
                            <div class="accordion-heading area">
                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#area1">Área #1</a>
                
                                
                            </div><!-- /Área -->
                
                            <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="area1" style="height: auto;">
                                <div class="accordion-inner">
                                    <div class="accordion" id="equipamento1">
                                        <!-- Equipamentos -->
                
                                        <div class="accordion-group">
                                            <div class="accordion-heading equipamento">
                                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#equipamento1-1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ponto1-1">Equipamento #1-1</a>
                
                                                
                                            </div><!-- Pontos -->
                
                                            <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="ponto1-1" style="height: auto;">
                                                <div class="accordion-inner">
                                                    <div class="accordion" id="servico1">
                                                        <div class="accordion-group">
                                                            <div class="accordion-heading ponto">
                                                                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#servico1-1-1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#servico1-1-1">Ponto
                                                                #1-1-1</a>
                
                                                                
                                                            </div><!-- Serviços -->
                
                                                            <div class="accordion-body in collapse" id="servico1-1-1" style="height: auto;">
                                                                <div class="accordion-inner">
                                                                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right">
                                                                            </i> Serviço
                                                                            #1-1-1-1</a>
                                                                        </li>
                
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right">
                                                                            </i> Serviço
                                                                            #1-1-1-2</a>
                                                                        </li>
                
                                                                        <li>
                                                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right">
                                                                            </i> Serviço
                                                                            #1-1-1-3</a>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div><!-- /Serviços -->
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div><!-- /Pontos -->
                                        </div><!-- /Equipamentos -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /accordion -->
                </div> 
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help....

Answer (score 0):

may be this code useful for you:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "viz/getcachedata",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    //may be your data like that
    var responce = {
      areas: [{
        name: "Areaa1",
        equipamento: [{
          name: "Eeequipamento11"
        }, {
          name: "Eeequipamento12"
        }]
      }, {
        name: "Areaa2",
        equipamento: [{
          name: "Eeequipamento21"
        }, {
          name: "Eeequipamento22"
        }]
      }, {
        name: "Areaa3",
        equipamento: [{
          name: "Eeequipamento31"
        }, {
          name: "Eeequipamento32"
        }]
      }]
    }
    var html = '<div class="accordion"><div class="accordion-group">';

    //loop for areas
    responce.areas.forEach(function(val, key) {
      html += '<div class="accordion-heading area"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#' + val.name + '">' + val.name + '</a></div>';
      html += '<div class="accordion-body collapse" id="' + val.name + '" style="height: auto;"><div class="accordion-inner">';
      console.log(val.equipamento);
      html += '<div class="accordion" id="equipamento1"><div class="accordion-group">';
      val.equipamento.forEach(function(equip, equipkey) {
        html += '<div class="accordion-heading equipamento"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#equipamento1-1" data-toggle="collapse" href="#' + equip.name + '">' + equip.name + '</a></div><div class="accordion-body collapse" id="' + equip.name + '" style="height: auto;"><div class="accordion-inner">dfdsfsdf</div></div>';
      });
      html += '</div></div>';
      html += '</div></div>';
    });
    html += '</div></div>';
    $('#menulistitem1').html(html);
  }
});
```

Comment: it works only once... once collapse the elements these wont expand, for result i need to refresh the page again.. It is partially working